# Phpmailer dejó de funcionar

Tags: email, phpmailer

Estoy trabajando en una función de recuperación de contraseña través de correo electrónico implementando phpmailer.

Esta es la conexión:

```
<?php 
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$password = "";
$db = "db_barangay";

$conexion = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $db);

if($conexion->connect_errno){
  echo "Falló la conexión a la base de datos " . $conexion->connect_error;
}
?>
```

Aquí la función para enviar el correo:

```
<?php 
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;

require 'PHPMailer/Exception.php';
require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php';
require 'PHPMailer/SMTP.php';

require_once('connection.php');
if(isset($_POST['btn_recovery'])){
    
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM tbluser where username = '".$username."'";
    $result = $conexion->query($query);
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

    if($result->num_rows > 0){
    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);

        try {
            $mail->isSMTP();
            $mail->Host       = 'smtp-mail.outlook.com';
            $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
            $mail->Username   = 'luchadores@outlook.com';
            $mail->Password   = 'Clave';
            $mail->Port       = 587;
            $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';

            $mail->setFrom('luchadores@outlook.com');
            $mail->addAddress($username, 'Administrador');
            $mail->isHTML(true);
            $mail->Subject = 'Recuperación de contraseña';
            $mail->Body    = 'Hola, este es un correo generado para solicitar tu recuperación de contraseña, por favor, visita la página de <a href="localhost/consejo_comunal/recovery/change_password.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Recuperación de contraseña</a>';

            $mail->send();
            header("Location: ../login.php?message=ok");
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            //header("Location: ../login.php?message=error");
            echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        }

    }
    else{
    header("Location: ../login.php?message");
    }
}
```

Al principio si funcionaba, hice varias pruebas y recibí los correos sin problemas tanto en gmail como en outlook.

Revise preguntas similares aquí e intenté añadir el SMTPSecure que en principio no tenía, también descargué la última versión de php mailer y me sigue dando este mismo error:

> Error de correo: Error de SMTP: no se pudo conectar al host SMTP. La conexión falló. stream_socket_enable_crypto (): la operación SSL falló con el código 1. Mensajes de error de OpenSSL: error: 1416F086: rutinas SSL: tls_process_server_certificate: verificación de certificado fallida Error del servidor SMTP: comando QUIT fallido

No se si este método tiene límite de correos o que puede ser porque como mencioné antes en un principio funcionó y de repente empezó a darme el error, por favor ayudenme a solucionar o recomienden una mejor opción por favor.

Comment: Hola. ¿Ya revisaste [esto](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#certificate-verification-failure) y verificaste todo lo que allí se indica?